# Seasonic EPS cable in EVGA PCI-E psu plug

Tags: power-supply, gpu, connector, eps

I have an Nvidia Tesla card to install with an EPS connector.

I have an EPS cable from my Seasonic Focus PSU that I plugged in my EVGA supernova 850w PSU and I checked with a multimeter and I get +12v on 3 of the 4 pins on the top row (close to the clip)

Do I have any chance of frying my card if I plug this in? I think I'm fine since when I look at the EPS pinout all 4 top pins are +12v but in my case I have 3 pins +12v and the 4 bottom pins gnd and the 4th top pin gnd.

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spsgx.png

From this image I can say that my pins 1-4 and 8 are ground and pins 5-7 are 12v.

And I want to plug in my Tesla card that expects 12v on pins 5-8.

Just to clarify I'm not trying to plug a PCIe cable in an EPS plug. It's and EPS cable from a Seasonic PSU that plugs in a PCIe connector on the PSU and outputs the 12v on the right row of the EPS connector but only 3 of the 4 12v pins are active.

Comment: It will short-circuit the 12 V and gnd when plugged into the card, so do not use that cable on that power supply.

Comment: Oh yeah it's possible I didn't think of that. It's kinda weird though that a cable made to go from PCIe to EPS could cause a short on pin 8. Thanks for the input.